# How to fill image in full screen size in React

Tags: react-native

How can I fill an image in full screen size in React?

I looked many blogs and codes, but all of them are not working for me.

Please help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For React-Native, you need to use the **flex** attribute.

```
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  View,
  Image
} = React;

var ImgComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.imgCtner}>
        <Image style={styles.img} source={{uri: 'http://images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png![Description here][2]'}} />
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  imgCtner: {
    alignItems: 'stretch'
    flex: 1,
  },
  img: {
    flex: 1
  }
});
```

================= Below is for web ====================

Actually what **React** does is just simply render your component and give you other benefits like **easy to compose your components.** **It doesn't change the basic concept of how web page works**.

You can do it in this way,

```
var ImageCtner = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var url = '/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';
        return (
            <div className='full-page-image'>
                <img src={url} />
            </div>
        );
    }
});

//render you component here...
```

Then in your style file, you can write down you styles.

```
.full-page-image {
     position: absolute;
     top: 0px;
     bottom: 0px;
     left: 0px;
     right: 0px;
}
.full-page-image img {
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

Hope this can solve your problem, and feel free to ask any questions. : )

Comment: Just notice, you are asking the React-Native... I will update my answer, one second.